# Stuck on boot, on 'loading initial ramdisk' or dropped to busybox

Tags: boot, 16.04

I'm dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on an MSI GT72S. Of the kernels I have installed, I can only ever boot with 4.4.0-36, that too usually after a couple of tries. Anything more recent than that just gets stuck on boot, either at "Loading initial ramdisk" when selected from 'Advanced options' in the grub menu, or drops me to a 'busybox' prompt after a minute or so when selected as the default newest kernel.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I needed to add `intel_idle.max_cstate=0` to grub to get anything usable at all.

How do I diagnose what is going wrong and fix it?

Comment: Same problem here. Except the situation is simpler, just vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 install with full disk encryption, "4.4.0-36-generic" boots but "4.4.0-38-generic" just gives "Loading Linux 4.4.0-38-generic ...\n  Loading initial ramdisk ...". On initial boot without going through the "advanced options" dialog the error comes for me at the  "Please unlock disk sda3_crypt" screen which freezes.

Comment: Workarounds (using "Advanced options for Ubuntu"): Boot an older kernel or **use "recovery mode"**.   The @Scolvin answer also sort of worked for me (by disabling the boot menu), but it somehow reverted after one boot.

Comment: How did you install the kernel? for what it is worth; I have `4.4.0-34` and intend to stay with it, for stability. The only possible update path that I see to be reasonably stable is that provided by https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack - anything else and you might be "on your own" in the realm of developers, running code with a low amount of testing, if any at all .

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure this was the same problem I had but my problem was related to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-debug-installer/+bug/1359689) issue with LVM2/LUKS. The solution was to set

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

in `/etc/default/grub`, then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to boot into recovery mode, and in the driver menu switch off the nvidia driver and back onto it. I think it doesn't update correctly with Linux kernel updates

Comment: I don't see any driver menu in recovery options....

Comment: the recovery mode used to get into the system desktop, and use the regular driver manager from there. I had a funky case where I had to [declare `nomodeset` in the kernel line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/), best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer from the Windows menu rather than shutting down, then booting straight into Linux.

After booting into Windows (10) then shutting down, I was getting this error. I saw elsewhere that some people were having issues with CMOS at this same time. I was starting to think it might have something to do with time (Windows and Linux seem to handle time differently).

My intent was to go into Windows and manually adjust the time, but it was already correct. I then restarted the computer from the Windows menu and Xubuntu started up normally.

Answer (score 0):

Went to the recovery mode of Ubuntu kernel by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and there I chose upgrade packages, if it did not work as it seemed it did not find my internet connection. So I continued starting into a recovery mode startup, there I run `sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade`, restarted and it worked.